# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined in ionic3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to search the product based on the string passed by the user

```
getItems(): void {
  let search = event.target.value;
  if (search && search.trim() != '') {
    this.productService.getProducts(search).subscribe((products) => {
      console.dir(products);
    }, (err) => {
       console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

When I try to search by passing query it is showing below error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

I'm not able to figure out where I went to wrong . Could any one please help me

Comment: Did you tried my answer. Your code wrong you can change just this line getItems(event){}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is an event... It shall be passed into the function

```
getItems(event)
```

Furthermore. Its a good practise to check the property before using it. I mean target property of event object

Event binding might be assign differently. But in your case - it might be KeyUp of the input field or Click events on the button (but then you need to refer to the field)

```
<input (keyup)="getItems($event)" />

or 

<input #my-input />
<button (click)="getItems($event)" />
```

in the second example you don't need $event - because it will not refer to the value. Yet you need to use ViewChild decorator function to get the value from the input

Answer (score 1):

Here is the possible way to do this the most people using two way data binding only.It is used to get data and bind data.

First way:-

Html File,

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchTxt" name="searchTxt" (keyup)="getItems()" />
```

Typescript file,

```
public searchTxt:any;

constructor(){
   //this.searchTxt="some value"; //here you can assign value to search box
}

getItems(): void {
  let search = this.searchTxt; // here iam accessing value from textbox.
  if (search && search.trim() != '') {
    this.productService.getProducts(search).subscribe((products) => {
      console.dir(products);
    }, (err) => {
       console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Second way:-
From your code you missed some minor part, here you will see.

Html File,

```
<input (keyup)="getItems($event)" />
```

Typescript file,

```
getItems(): void { //here you misssed to recieve an argument to a function calling statement
```

so change like this

```
getItems(event): void { //here iam recieving argument used some variable name
  let search = event.target.value;
  if (search && search.trim() != '') {
    this.productService.getProducts(search).subscribe((products) => {
      console.dir(products);
    }, (err) => {
       console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

I hope you understand what you missed some line your code and also how to use two way data binding.

While using two way binding `[(ngModel)]` you have to include `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts` file,